# Why isn't my UITableViewCell adjusting in landscape in Cocoa Touch?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have successfully made a `UITableViewCell` whose height changes depending on the content (using `sizeWithFont`).  I am currently trying to make my app work in every orientation, so I had to make a few changes to my code.  The first thing I did was add some code that reloads the tableView whenever the orientation is changed.  This causes `sizeWithFont` to correct the size of the table cell.  When I start in portrait orientation, I can rotate the device in any direction and the  `UITableViewCell` will automatically adjust to fit to the size of the text.

However, I have run into a problem when the orientation is left or right whenever the table is initially loaded.  The width of the cell (the variable `widthVar` in the code below) outputs to be 300, which is the width of the cell in portrait orientation.  The expected output is 440.  This causes an unwanted margin in the table view cell.  How can I make it so that I get the correct width of the cell?

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"plainDetail";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        }

        UILabel *enchantmentLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:402];
        enchantmentLabel.text = [self.enchantmentResultsBrain getDescription:self.enchantmentAndLevel];
        CGFloat widthVar = cell.textLabel.frame.size.width;

        NSLog(@"size: %f", widthVar);

        CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(widthVar, 9999);

        CGSize expectedLabelSize = [enchantmentLabel.text sizeWithFont:enchantmentLabel.font 
                                                                           constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize 
                                                                               lineBreakMode:enchantmentLabel.lineBreakMode];

        return expectedLabelSize.height+10;
}
```

Comment: So you're getting a cell that's for portrait orientation in landscape? How are you instantiating your table view?

Comment: It's in a UITableViewController.  It does it automatically.

Comment: Check to see that the view containing your table is set to Portrait.. Are you running your app on the device or the simulator?

Comment: Simulator.  It is portrait...